# Mock the std::move() function to assess its performance impact

Tags: c++, testing, c++11

I would like to "mock" the `std::move()` function to assess its (positive) performance impact on a C++ library I have written.

I have used `std::move()` extensively and I would like to avoid `grep`ping everywhere to remove it. What is the best way to replace it with an identity function? I'm compiling with `gcc`.

Comment: Removing all you explicit `std::move` calls wouldn't prevent all the implicit calls to move constructors anyway.

Comment: You do know that `move` and `forward` don't actually move or forward?  They do a compiler no-op reinterpretation of the input as a r-value reference (sometimes for `forward`).  Any actual moving happens during move-construction or -assignment.  Try those spots to profile.

Comment: @CTMacUser: I do know. Yes. That's why I think that removing my std::move calls may cause less move-constructors or -assignments to be actually called, in favor of their "copy-" brothers.

Answer (score 1):

This should "work" but it's actually undefined behaviour:

```
// Standard library includes must be above.

#define move not_a_move

namespace std {
    template<typename T>
    typename std::remove_lvalue_reference<T>::type const&
    not_a_move(T&& x)
    {
        return x;
    }
}
```

This won't capture implicit moves or moves done inside the standard library itself. I would recommend just removing all your uses of `std::move`; it's cleaner and actually allowed. :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain there is no way to achieve this short of massacring your own code to remove all the move constructors on the large objects you're wanting to profile. You may also find you would then have problems with passing non rvalue references to functions expecting rvalue references.

So I would suggest not bothering and accept that it's highly likely your code is faster and be satisfied with that.

I actually wanted to try this a year or so ago, and never found a way.

Comment: I don't want to remove the move constructors: sometimes I can't, because they're in the STL. I want to mock my `std::move` calls, that may actually prevent some copies to happen.